# What is the Christian symbol of the unicorn, and what does it suggest?

Tags: symbolism, animals

What is the Christian symbol of the unicorn, and what does it suggest?  I have seen it in the seals of certain churches.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here.  When you get a chance, be sure to check out the [site tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up on  how this site is [a little different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) than other sites around the web. *This is not a comment on the quality of your question, but rather a standard welcome message.*

Comment: Could you give us some examples of where you have seen this symbol?